# Can VS Code Test Explorer Catch2 extension automatically outdate tests when sources change

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, meson-build, test-explorer, catch2

I'm using **VS Code Test Explorer** with **python** extension on a project.  It is awesome.  If I change any source files, the relevant tests in Test explorer will be highlighted as out of date so I know I have to run them again to check everything is ok.

I'm trying to do the same thing with a **C/C++** project and the Test Explorer Catch2 extension.  I have a simple meson project file to build my test executable(s).

It works well in that my tests are discovered and I can run them, **HOWEVER if I change a source file it the tests wont show as out of date to indicate that they need to be rerun**.

I know this is a dependency issue with meson (or what ever build system that VS Code understands).

**Is there a Test Explorer (or VS Code) way of for determining which exes are out of date and need building (tests and build in general)?**

Comment: I've found the following, which may be possible solutions.    https://mesonbuild.com/IDE-integration.html    https://github.com/prozum/meson-cmake-wrapper

Comment: Seems the meson-cmake-wrapper is no currently maintained, so maybe plain old CMake might have to be the answer for now.   Sad for meson fanboy :(